# Foreign key chaining

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, multiple-tables, cascading-deletes

Can I have a model like this:

```
create table address (address_id int primary key, .....);
create table event (event_id int primary key,.....);
create table event_addresses (
     event_id int foreign key references event(event_id), 
     address_id int foreign key references address(address_id),
     primary key (event_id, address_id)
); 
create table user_events(
     user_id int foreign key references users(user_id),
     event_id int foreign key references event_addresses(event_id) on delete cascade,
     primary key (user_id, event_id)
);
```

so that whenever an event address is changed the entry in event_addresses can be deleted and that cascades down to user_events. Is it a good practice to chain foreign keys this way?